# Video HTML 5 don't work with Php

Tags: php, html, video

I'v searched, but didn't find any answers.

So, here's my problem.

I try to get the link of a video, and then, use this link in the  HTML5 :

So, i have this :

```
<?php

$monFichier = file_get_contents('http://streamzzz.com/page/american-horror-story-saison-3-episode-8'); 

$fichier = htmlentities($monFichier); 
$occur = strpos($monFichier, "http://youwatch.org/embed");

$test = substr($monFichier, $occur, 51);

$files = file_get_contents($test);
$files = htmlentities($files);
$occur2 = strpos($files, "|mp4|video|");
$substring = substr($files, $occur2+11, 69);

$substring = explode( "|", $substring);
?>

<?php
$link='http://'.$substring[2].'.youwatch.org:'.$substring[1].'/'.$substring[0].'/video.mp4';
```

This work. Finally i get a correct URL for the video.

But the problem is :

```
<video src="<?php echo $link ?>" controls></video>
```

i can't read the video. But when i click right, and click to open on a new tab, the link work well, and download the video.

And if i manually write the link get by my first script, this work too. But when i write

```
<?php echo $link?>
```

it doesn't work.

Something strange is that's work on IE, but not on chrome or firefox
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Missed a semicolon after `$link` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $link; ?>
----------------^
```